# Json with RabbitMQ

Tags: android, json, rabbitmq

I have a problem sending Json messages with RabbitMQ using Android.

I have to parse RabbitMQ object to string and bytes to send the message

```
channel.basicPublish("", Cola_RPC, props, mensaje_parseado.toString().getBytes()); //Mensaje_parseado is the Json
```

When I recive the message I don't know how to parse into Json again to get the original message.

I try:

```
String stringJSON = delivery.getBody().toString(); 
JSONObject respuesta_desparseada = new JSONObject (stringJSON);
```

But it doesn't work.

Maybe is a noobie question, but I can't reach the soluction on Google.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
String stringJSON = new String(delivery.getBody()); 
JSONObject respuesta_desparseada = new JSONObject (stringJSON);
```

You are calling `toString()` in a `byte[]` that uses the `toString()` method from `Object`.

If you want to see why, you can run this:

```
String myString = "myTest";
System.out.println(myString);
System.out.println(myString.getBytes());
System.out.println(myString.getBytes().toString());
System.out.println(new String(myString.getBytes()));
```